# Парситься только четвёртая страница сайта

Tags: python, json, парсер

Есть парсер авито, в парсере реализована пагинация, библиотека requests делает запрос на следующую страницу в цикле for page in range(1, 5), а после парсит её(парсит не requests, а BeautifulSoup4). Такая была задумка, но на деле код парсит только 4-ую страницу.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import json

# url = 'https://www.avito.ru/murmansk/gotoviy_biznes?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD'
headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
}
file = 'avito.csv'

# req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# src = req.text

def save_file(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Название', 'Цена', 'Дата'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'], item['price'], item['date']])

def get_content(src):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='iva-item-content-m2FiN')

    info = []
    for item in items:

        try:
            title = item.find('h3', class_='title-root-395AQ iva-item-title-1Rmmj title-listRedesign-3RaU2 title-root_maxHeight-3obWc text-text-1PdBw text-size-s-1PUdo text-bold-3R9dt').get_text(strip=True)
        except AttributeError:
            title= 'Не указано'

        price = item.find('span', class_='price-text-1HrJ_ text-text-1PdBw text-size-s-1PUdo').get_text(strip=True)

        try:
            date = item.find('div', class_='date-text-2jSvU text-text-1PdBw text-size-s-1PUdo text-color-noaccent-bzEdI').get_text(strip=True)
        except AttributeError:
            date = 'Не указано'

        info.append({
            'title': title,
            'price': price,
            'date': date
            })

        with open('info.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(info, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)



def parse():

    for page in range(1, 5):

        req = requests.get(f'https://www.avito.ru/rossiya/gotoviy_biznes?p={page}&q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD', headers=headers)
        src = req.text
        get_content(src)




parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам, изменил флаг в функции save_file, был флаг w, поменял на флаг a, также добавил вызов функции save_file после цикла(в функции get_content), решение оказалось довольно простым.